# Query error: WHERE `someDateTime` IS NULL OR `someDateTime` < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAYS

Tags: mysql

I want to select users whose `someDateTime` field is either NULL, or older than 3 days ago.

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `users`
WHERE `someDateTime` IS NULL
OR `someDateTime` < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAYS
LIMIT 1
```

I receive a syntax error with this query.
I also tried `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAYS)` but that fails too.

Comment: when i need to do this, i used to split date in mysql and get mont, day, and year separated to compare, it works fine for me, and could be an idea

Comment: can you try my answer ?

Comment: I think that's DAY, not DAYS; but next time, be sure to include the text of the syntax error.

Comment: Yep that was it  thanks !

Comment: You should then accept (possibly even upvote) the relevant useful answer through the checkmark displayer to its left, so whoever happened to stumble on this page next will quickly find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss the bracket and

use **DAY** only instead of **DAYS**.

and more use **CURDATE()** instead of **NOW()**. and use **=** to get  data of today date.

`CURDATE()` returns the DATE part of the current time. [Manual on CURDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

`NOW()` returns the date and time portions as a timestamp in various formats, depending on how it was requested. [Manual on NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `users`
WHERE `someDateTime` IS NULL
OR `someDateTime` <=
( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY )
```

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer since I think this is what the user **is looking for**, but you ought to specify the change from DAYS to DAY, and, more importantly, explain the difference between `NOW()` and `CURDATE()`. If - as I suspect - the OP wants something like "users who have not logged in since 3 days ago" or similar, there *is* a significant difference. Otherwise, your answer is not what the user **said** he wants.

Comment: Yep, it's `DAY` not `DAYS` (so it's not just about the brackets, I'm not sure the bracket bring anything at all but I added them for clarity anyway and just incase they are needed). Also it's `<=` not `=<`

Comment: I said that because the initial answer was saying it was about the brackets (his code had `DAY` right but he didn't mention that was the issue)

Comment: Also, I do need the date AND time portion, so I believe NOW() is more appropriate (values in the db inserted in datetime format using NOW())

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT  DATE_ADD(Date(NOW()), INTERVAL 3 DAY)

or 

SELECT  DATE_ADD(Date(NOW()), INTERVAL -3 DAY)
```

Then subtract your DB date or any....

Comment: Maybe you meant sub

Comment: Sorry what i mean is he can do whatever he wanted to do after in where statement.